# NHibernate: Is there a way to work out if an object is persisted or not?

Tags: nhibernate

I was wondering if there is actually an existing way to work out if an object is persisted yet or not? For instance an *IsPersisted(object obj)* method...

Checking the identifier for an empty value would work I'm sure, but I haven't fully thought this through and just wanted to be sure there wasn't something I was missing.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the id against the `unsaved-value` is a good way. That's what the `session.SaveOrUpdate` method uses to decide whether to emit an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 4):

This is the entity persister's responsibility, so I'd let it figure it out instead of manually checking the unsaved-value:

```
public bool? IsPersisted(object obj, ISession session)
{
    var sessionFactoryImpl = (ISessionFactoryImplementor)session.SessionFactory;
    var persister = new SessionFactoryHelper(sessionFactoryImpl).RequireClassPersister(obj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
    return !persister.IsTransient(obj, (ISessionImplementor)session);
}
```

The [entity persister does a few more things](https://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Persister/Entity/AbstractEntityPersister.cs?r=5130#l3627) than just checking the unsaved-value, like checking the version and the second-level cache. And it seems that it's not always possible to find out if it's transient (it returns `bool?`).

Comment: Using NHibernate 3.3.2.4000, I could not get this to work. Using `Type.FullName` instead of `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` resolved this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following ISession extension, which seems to work.  If you've got something better, I'd be happy to see it.

```
    public static bool IsNewEntity(this ISession session, object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return false;

        ISessionImplementor sessionImpl = session.GetSessionImplementation();
        IPersistenceContext persistenceContext = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext;
        EntityEntry oldEntry = persistenceContext.GetEntry(entity);

        return oldEntry == null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate potentially looks at three different properties to see if an entity is persisted. In most cases checking the Id against the unsaved-value is sufficient. If the Id is assigned, a Version or Timestamp property will be checked.

1. Id - this works if the id is not assigned.
2. Version - if present and if the id is assigned.
3. Timestamp - if present and if the id is assigned.